# C for loop troubleshooting

Tags: c

So basically I was creating a program to ask the user how many times they wanted to test the program.But I couldnt figure out the problem with my for loop. So:

1. If the user wants to test the program 3 times, it should ask for the value of a 3 times only and it should quit after.

This is my code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{


    int test;
    printf("How many times do you want to test the program?");
    scanf("%d", &test);
    test = 0; // Reinitializing the test from 0
    for (test=0; test=>1; test++) //I cant figure out whats going on with the for loop.
    {
        printf("Enter the value of a: \n");
        scanf("%d", &test);
        ;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be:
"How many times do you want to test the program": 3
Enter the value of a : any numerical value
Enter the value of a: any numerical value
Enter the value of a: any numerical value
(exit)

Comment: You read test and then immediately set it to zero.

Comment: Do you understand how loops work?

Comment: [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: But isn't it possible with a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

In this section of your code:

```
scanf("%d", &test);
test = 0; // Reinitializing the test from 0
for (test=0; test=>1; test++)
```

First, memory owned by `test` is populated with a value entered by user.  (this is OK)
Next, you nullify that new value in memory by setting `test` to zero.  (this is not OK)
finally the construction of your loop statement is incorrect.

In a correct version of your `for` loop, `test` should be a value used as a limit against which an index is tested as that index is incremented across a range of values, for example, from 0 to some positive value.

You probably intended:

```
scanf("%d", &test);
//test = 0; // Reinitializing the test from 0 (leave this out)
for(int i = 0; i <= test; i++)
{
    ...
```

Where a separate index value (`i`) is incremented and tested against the limit `test`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It finally works and I now understand the problems in it.